# Hide items, even if there are items in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have listMonth as my initialView in FullCalendar.

[image: List of items]

Here's my FullCalendar js:

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'listMonth',
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'listMonth',
    },
    locale: 'en',
    timeZone: 'Asia/Almaty',
    height: 800,
    weekends: false
```

I want to hide items that will appear in weekends

FullCalendar v5.8.0

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/weekends says it controls _"Whether to include Saturday/Sunday **columns** in any of the calendar views"_ (my bold). Since the listMonth view doesn't have any _columns_, it seems logical that this setting doesn't apply to it. The setting controls the display of certain views...it doesn't purposely exclude events from your feed. If you want that you'll likely have to code it yourself.

Comment: P.S. If you want to fully confirm that this is the expected behaviour you'd have to raise a ticket with the fullCalendar team directly - see https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs for details